# Magit Can't Find Git

Tags: git, emacs, magit

My emacs plugin magit can't find the right git path.

I saw the source code of magit,found magit use this shell command to find git:

```
git.exe -c "alias.exe=!which git | cygpath -wf -" "exe"
```

I don't understand this shell command.

But it return the wrong path of git.

Environment：

```
os: windows 10
git: 1.9.0.msysgit.0
emacs: 24.5
magit: 2.4.0
```

Comment: Above that part of the code, magit attempts to use `executable-find` to find `git.exe`. If your `git.exe` is in your `exec-path`, that should find it.

Comment: I run the command in windows shell,but it output the wrong path.I just don't understand the why it come out the wrong path.Because it looks like a normal git config command.